# Display XML in proper formatted way

Tags: php, simplexml

Is there any way to show XML data in a good and readable format using PHP? I know I can build code to do this, but is there a function that does something similar I can reuse?

eg:

```
<animals><animal><name>Lion</name><type>Stay away</type></animal><animal><name>Koala Bear</name><type>Hug</type></animal></animals>
```

Is there some code that will show me the data in a decent format? eg:

```
Animal
  Name - Lion
  Type - Stay Away
Animal
  Name - Koala Bear
  Type - Hug
```

Some kind of XML to HTML display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is called [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) and there is a [XSL class in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php).

With XSLT you can transform XML documents basically to any kind of output.

Answer (score 1):

It is called XSLT, you can transform XML into anything.
[link text](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/ref.xslt.php)